# Placeholders are not replaced

Tags: go, go-templates

I am experimenting with the package `http/template`.
I have also already managed that e.g. the header, footer, navbar and so on were included  in the base template:

```html
{{ define "base" }}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <!-- Start Head -->
    <head>
        {{ template "head" }}
    </head>
    <!-- End Head -->

    <!-- Start Body -->
    <body>
    {{ template "navbar" }}
    {{ template "content" }}
    {{ template "footer" }}
    </body>
    <!-- End Body -->
    </html>
{{ end }}
```

404 page:

```html
{{ define "content" }}
    [...]
                    <h1 class="text-light text-right">404</h1>
                    <small>{{.CurrentURL}}</small>
    [...]
{{ end }}
```

So here the variable `CurrentURL` should be replaced by the current URL.
However, this is only displayed empty (`""`) on the website:

```html
<small></small>
```

But now I want to replace a variable, which is displayed on the web page only as "".

Go Code:
Parser:

```golang
func (parser *TemplateParser) ParseTemplate(name string) (tpl *template.Template, err error) {
  root, err := template.New("root").Parse(rootTmpl)
  // ...
  return root.ParseFiles(files...)
}
```

Route:

```golang
func (ws *WebServer) Exec(name string, r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter, data map[string]interface{}) (err error) {
    // ...
    // add default data
    data["CurrentURL"] = r.URL.RequestURI()

    // ...
    return tpl.Execute(w, data)
}
```

Even with an array, I can't use `range` etc:

```golang
    type Test struct {
        CurrentURL string
        C []string
    }

    t := Test{
        CurrentURL: "Current URL",
        C: []string {"C1", "c2", "ccc4"},
    }

    tpl.Execute(w, t)
```

```html
 <ul>
{{range .C}}
  <li>{{.}}</li>
{{end}}
</ul>
<!-- No <li></li> is created -->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the context to the instantiated templates. Use

```
{{ template "content" .}}
```

to pass the data in `.` to the `content` template.

Comment: Oh, such a small dot, and I'm searching myself silly. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing any data to the child templates. [Per the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

```
{{template "name"}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.

{{template "name" pipeline}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
    to the value of the pipeline.
```